# Handle Authorization in shared Backend for Blazor server and WASM

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, authorization

I am creating a Blazor server application and trying to use the Backend for a possible future WASM or Angular frontend as well. So, to let the backend behave as much as a REST API as possible, every time I use a backend service, I create a scope (as a regular .NET Core API would do on its own on each HTTP call) like this:

```
using var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
var myService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
myService.CallBackendMethod();
```

I mostly do this to avoid trouble with meant-to-be short-living services, especially when using EFCore.

This works fine as long as it does not come to Authorization. In a regular .NET Core API, you would have things like `[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Roles.Create)]` above my Controllers and could get my username and user-specific claims in the backend like this:

```cs
public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    Claims = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Claims.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Type, item.Value)).ToList();
}
```

But how could I handle that in a Blazor server app? I know I can use the `CascadingParameter` `AuthenticationStateTask` to get my claims like that:

```cs
[CascadingParameter]
public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

public void GetClaims()
{
    var claims = AuthenticationStateTask.Result.User.Claims;
}
```

However, I am unsure if this is best practice, and I have to use a different backend for Blazor Server and Blazor WASM because the `AuthenticationStateTask` can not be used in my backend methods. I want to behave the Backend the same, whether it is a Blazor Server or a Blazor WASM application.

Comment: I don't get your point, if you want to use authorize, you could use authorize view or authorize attribute, if you want to get the claims, you could use await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() to get it. Why you need to use different thing?